# WHERE not working

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Any thoughts on why `WHERE` clause would not work? I have made sure I have double checked the coding and spelling etc. It will not work with a simple `WHERE` clause, and I have tried using different operators, operators that I know are in the table.  I have tried using trailing spaces, I have copied and pasted the output from `SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM table`.  In short I have really made sure that it is not just some dumb error on my part before posting this question.

Here are the specs of the column that is giving me trouble.  `UTF8_General_Ci` and it `VARCHAR(100)`.

I have never had any problems with a `WHERE` clause, not like this at least.  Any thought?  Thanks in advance

Here is the code;

> SELECT site_specialty 
>   FROM site WHERE site_specialty='INTERNAL MEDICINE'

there is no error message, it just comes up blank 0 rows returned

Comment: gotta post the code bud

Comment: Is there a row in the `site` table with that value for `site_specialty`?

Comment: @Joachim several thousand.  I have tried using several different values

Comment: @Rahil The table is `site`

Comment: Try `SELECT site_specialty FROM site WHERE replace(site_specialty, ' ', '' )=replace('INTERNAL MEDICINE', ' ', '')`

Comment: Sounds like you may have a trailing space or similar in your values. How about `WHERE site_specialty LIKE 'INTERNAL MEDICINE%'`?

Comment: @Joachim that worked thanks! but why didn't it work when I just tried `WHERE site_specialty = 'INTERNAL MEDICINE '` (blank at the end)

Comment: @RahilWazir Er... say what?

Comment: @user3548821 There may be more than one trailing space.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: trailing spaces are ignored silently while compared.

Comment: @Ravinder will `REPLACE` work with the trailing space then? `UPDATE site SET site_specialty=REPLACE(site_specialty,'INTERNAL MEDICINE ','INTERNAL MEDICINE')` Just tried it and it didn't

Comment: If `site_speciality` is a set of words that contain `'internal medicine '` then, `replace` should work.

Comment: Is there any way to do use a wildcard % in `REPLACE` ?  The `REPLACE`with a trailing space did not work

Comment: There must be more than a single space between those two words.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Yes, on tabs trailing, it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT site_specialty FROM site WHERE site_specialty LIKE '%INTERNAL MEDICINE%'
```

Comment: A trailing `%` is not a problem, but note that by putting a leading `%`, you'll take away the database's ability to use indexes in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

Before giving up entirely, I would try:

```
SELECT site_specialty
FROM site
WHERE upper(site_specialty) like '%INTERNAL%MEDICINE%';
```

Comment: OP claims `UTF8_General_Ci`

Comment: @Ravinder . . . The OP claimed the column is case insensitive.  There are also database collations to consider because the expression includes a constant.

Comment: I did not get. If an expression is used, then `ci` will be ignored?

Comment: @Ravinder . . . The rules collation rules for `like` are not well documented, so I figured it would be helpful to make the expression as general as possible.  I'm not 100% sure what happens with `like` when there is a collation conflict.